# How to retain site login in MS Edge from one PC to another or after reformat?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, user-profiles

In Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 after I login to superuser.com say, next time when I access superuser.com again in MS Edge I am automatically logged in to my username account.

Like that I have a few more sites where Edge has preserved the login. This is NOT `Saved Password` option. I think this is done thru cookies, because after I clear them the auto login is lost.
I am going to reformat my Windows 10 PC but somehow wish to preserve this setting/profile/cookies or whatever applicable, so that MS Edge on reformatted PC, I will be able to autologin to those sites when accessed.

Is there any way to do that for MS Edge?

What I tried so far.

I am testing this in a VM by recreating same username in another instance of Windows 10.
For MS Edge I copied `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data`
To another VM but while all other details like history etc were retained, the login is lost.

Sign-in to MS account to sync is the last option if that's going to work.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do a backup/restore Edge cookies?

Try [Cookies by lfj.io - Microsoft Edge Addons](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/cookies-by-lfjio/jpnjjfanpdfjhjmajbobeibhollmgjhd):

> KEY FEATURES
>
> 1. **Cookies file's Export/Import**.
> 2. File encryption performed by AES and Rijndael algorithm.
> 3. It's compatible with netscape cookie file format, therefore cookies.txt files from wget, curl, youtube-dl, ... can also imported.
> 4. Cloud export and cloud import: synchronize cookies with the lfj.io service, able to share them with member of your LFJ teams.
> 5. Smart identity: you don't need to register to use Cookies by lfj.io. With one device installed, you can sync with all other
>    devices. That your unique id  will never change even you remove and
>    reinstall this extension.
> 6. Cleanup tool with customizable options: Remove all cookies, your browsing data of the specified site by  one click.
> 7. Clean import : Option to allow remove existing cookies before each of new cookies import.
> 8. Additional backup and restore options: Not only cookies, all browsing data can able have backed-up by create  a cookies restore
>    point. You can export fully site state and all of browsing data of the
>    specified site. It allowed you restore all state of site back to the
>    point of the file was made.

<sup>(Disclaimer: I don't use Edge so I haven't tested this)</sup>